# Result-variation functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When it comes to result-variation functions in TypeScript, which one is better?

- Through the functions union?

```
type SomeType = () => number | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>)
```

- Or through the returned-type union?

```
type SomeType = () => number | string | Promise<string>
```

Is there a recommendation for this, or does it make absolutely no difference?

**UPDATE**

From what I understand now, this is TypeScript's synthetic type differentiation, one that translates in exactly the same JavaScript, and requires exactly the same handling. So the difference is purely in TypeScript, even though it carries identical logic.

This kind of makes it a weird one, not so easy to understand why the type isn't the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? They mean different things: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAjFAvFAFLgSmwD4oA7AVwQCMIAnIgHz0JKgGdg6BLMgcyYsiWUgAU6ibuwgAeTj37ECAKGWhIsRCjQAmbHmGlKNelGbzefM1HGTpcrpeKqAxnDKcoAM32sRUABYdAG4oAHowqDoIYAo6D3IqWjplNw9gbzJ0AC5NJFRITBwvUIi4AGtU908vMh1c+HzdfRLwsIrXaoyrHD9SAFkAQ2AACwA6OkGyABNEVlIxgFYoAH5AvVyAIhGIABtduE3SsOjY+PZEkzooOGuLfir0zIBmBq0CjH0+Y-oJFLSamQAm8mpA9Dhvm0KkA)

Comment: This is confusing. The logic of this type is that it should be the same, if you think about how JavaScript works. From your example, it looks like it is TypeScript that enforces the difference, separating two identical declarations that will always result into the same JavaScript execution in the end. There is no calling difference in JavaScript whether you expect a function that can return multiple types or it is a variable-function that returns one of the types.

Comment: But TypeScript is here to ensure the type safety. If you want a function that *only* produces numbers that's one thing, if you want one that produces either number or string, that's another. There is no logic to represent both as the same thing if you don't *want* both. It depends on how you intend to use these.

Comment: @VLAZ The idea behind type safety is to differentiate, by declaration, things that may require different handling. In our example, they may not, so there is no value in TypeScript telling us here that those two things are different, because they are not.

Comment: I disagree. If I have `f` with the first type declaration and I do `if (typeof f() === "number")` I can deduce that that inside the `if` body, `f` is `() => number`. Were `f` to use the second declaration, I have no guarantee of this. These are different function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

These are different.

- With this you are saying that SomeType is either a function that returns a number, or a function that returns a string or a function that returns a promise of a string. (Multiple functions)

```
type SomeType = () => number | (() => string) | (() => Promise<string>)
```

- With this one you are saying that SomeType is a function that returns either a number or a string or a promise of a string. (One function)

```
type SomeType = () => number | string | Promise<string>
```

So it really just depends on what you need.

Comment: To say that the two things are different, is to be able to come up with an example in JavaScript where the two results may need different handling. I cannot come up with one, because I believe there is no logical difference behind these two, it's just TypeScript synthetic difference that's just there, and for unknown reason.

Comment: Yeah I mostly agree with you. I mean in terms of preventing any errors when this transpiles into javascript, I don't think it does anything. I mean this could only be helpful in terms of typing restrictions if there's ever a case when it becomes helpful. But maybe we are overlooking something or there's a bigger picture for which this needs to behave that way.

Comment: "*But maybe we are overlooking something or there's a bigger picture for which this needs to behave that way.*" The *only* time the two behave the same is if you call `f()`, then check the result, then decide how to handle it. That's *one* way of using a function. You can also call `f()` and based on the first result decide how to handle any further one. First declaration allows it, the second doesn't. You can also repeatedly call `f()` and collect the results in an array, then process it. Depending on the signature, it's either a homogenous or contains mixed elements.

Comment: Further, a type you can return either an existing `SomeType` function or a new one that's, say `() => boolean`. As a simple example with `(f: SomeType | null) => f ?? (() => false)`. In this case, if the declaration was the first one, you simply get a widened type union. If it was the second, then you have a potentially different kind of function produced.